# powershell Write-Output format

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am finding what seems to be an inconsistency to the way a Write-Output line (which prints out a variable) should be formatted. I can't find any information on this, which makes me guess that I am misunderstanding what I am seeing.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Statement:

For most simple variables, the below will work:

```
Write-Output " This $testValue will print just fine."
```

However, I need to add a $() to the Write-Output line if the variable is part of an object:

```
Write-Output $("Removing old software from directory: " + $site.INSTALLDIR)
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Question: Is the above statement correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to print object property values, then it should be used with special syntax $() shown as below:-

```
Write-Output "Removing old software from directory: $($site.INSTALLDIR)"
```

In case you want to print the variable name as well, put a backtick before the variable usage. Example:-

```
Write-Output "Removing old software from directory (`$site.INSTALLDIR): $($site.INSTALLDIR)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So is doing the following ...  Write-Output " This $testValue will print just fine."  ... incorrect? This syntax still works for simple variables for some reason.

Comment: Basic data type (int, string, char, float etc) variables do not require above special syntax. Above syntax is only required for **object property values**.